# QTToolTip::showText() flashes inside a QMousePressEvent

Tags: qt

All

I am using QToolTip::showText inside a QMousePressEvent handler;

```
void PmCellsBasedMap::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent)
{
    if (mouseEvent->button() ==  Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        // mouse left button pressed
        QString str;
        if (getTip(mouseEvent->pos(), str))
        {
            QToolTip::showText(mouseEvent->globalPos(),str);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the QToolTip shows the text too quickly, I need to keep the mouse pressed state for a relative long time, it shows the text later.

My intention： when operator clicks the left mouse button, the QToolTip shows the text all the way and be updated when the next mouse button click action happens.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: What about to show the tooltip when the mouse is released (mouseReleaseEvent())?

Comment: Try to set true autoFillBackground property for the widget

Comment: QToolTip::showText seem to have a delay before it appears up, the official document says we can intercerpt it  with a QHelpEvent inside event() handler. However, QHelpEvent detects the mouse hover on a specific position between mouse moves.     I finally use another method, i.e. drawing the text with painter.drawText(QRect(),str) and painter.fillRect(QRect(),QColor(200,200,200,200))  to display the text inside a mousePressEvent handler.